# completely remove border at wpf button while "click"?

Tags: c#, wpf

The border of the button is not visible, but if you click it (and hold the button pressed) you could see a border - how to hide it?

```
<Button Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="Transparent"  BorderThickness="0" Focusable="False" Height=" 100" Width="100 ">
                <Button.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="Button">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property = "Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent" />
                                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </Button.Style>
                ololo</Button>
```

Is it possible to do without Control template? (It disables on click and other usefull staff)

I have added this to resource dictonary but problem id present:

```
 <ResourceDictionary>
            <Style x:Key="ButtonFocusVisual">
                <Setter Property="Control.Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate>
                            <Border>
                                <Rectangle 
            Margin="2"
            StrokeThickness="1"
            Stroke="#60000000"
            StrokeDashArray="1 2"/>
                            </Border>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>





            <!-- Fill Brushes -->

            <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="NormalBrush" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
                <GradientBrush.GradientStops>
                    <GradientStopCollection>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FFF" Offset="0.0"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#CCC" Offset="1.0"/>
                    </GradientStopCollection>
                </GradientBrush.GradientStops>
            </LinearGradientBrush>

            <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="HorizontalNormalBrush" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,0">
                <GradientBrush.GradientStops>
                    <GradientStopCollection>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FFF" Offset="0.0"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#CCC" Offset="1.0"/>
                    </GradientStopCollection>
                </GradientBrush.GradientStops>
            </LinearGradientBrush>

            <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="LightBrush" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
                <GradientBrush.GradientStops>
                    <GradientStopCollection>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FFF" Offset="0.0"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#EEE" Offset="1.0"/>
                    </GradientStopCollection>
                </GradientBrush.GradientStops>
            </LinearGradientBrush>

            <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="HorizontalLightBrush" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,0">
                <GradientBrush.GradientStops>
                    <GradientStopCollection>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FFF" Offset="0.0"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#EEE" Offset="1.0"/>
                    </GradientStopCollection>
                </GradientBrush.GradientStops>
            </LinearGradientBrush>

            <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="DarkBrush" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
                <GradientBrush.GradientStops>
                    <GradientStopCollection>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FFF" Offset="0.0"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#AAA" Offset="1.0"/>
                    </GradientStopCollection>
                </GradientBrush.GradientStops>
            </LinearGradientBrush>

            <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="PressedBrush" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
                <GradientBrush.GradientStops>
                    <GradientStopCollection>
                        <GradientStop Color="#BBB" Offset="0.0"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#EEE" Offset="0.1"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#EEE" Offset="0.9"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FFF" Offset="1.0"/>
                    </GradientStopCollection>
                </GradientBrush.GradientStops>
            </LinearGradientBrush>

            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="DisabledForegroundBrush" Color="#888" />

            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="DisabledBackgroundBrush" Color="#EEE" />

            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="WindowBackgroundBrush" Color="#FFF" />

            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SelectedBackgroundBrush" Color="#DDD" />

            <!-- Border Brushes -->

            <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="NormalBorderBrush" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
                <GradientBrush.GradientStops>
                    <GradientStopCollection>
                        <GradientStop Color="#CCC" Offset="0.0"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#444" Offset="1.0"/>
                    </GradientStopCollection>
                </GradientBrush.GradientStops>
            </LinearGradientBrush>

            <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="HorizontalNormalBorderBrush" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,0">
                <GradientBrush.GradientStops>
                    <GradientStopCollection>
                        <GradientStop Color="#CCC" Offset="0.0"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#444" Offset="1.0"/>
                    </GradientStopCollection>
                </GradientBrush.GradientStops>
            </LinearGradientBrush>

            <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="DefaultedBorderBrush" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
                <GradientBrush.GradientStops>
                    <GradientStopCollection>
                        <GradientStop Color="#777" Offset="0.0"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#000" Offset="1.0"/>
                    </GradientStopCollection>
                </GradientBrush.GradientStops>
            </LinearGradientBrush>

            <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="PressedBorderBrush" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
                <GradientBrush.GradientStops>
                    <GradientStopCollection>
                        <GradientStop Color="#444" Offset="0.0"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#888" Offset="1.0"/>
                    </GradientStopCollection>
                </GradientBrush.GradientStops>
            </LinearGradientBrush>

            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="DisabledBorderBrush" Color="#AAA" />

            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SolidBorderBrush" Color="#888" />

            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="LightBorderBrush" Color="#AAA" />

            <!-- Miscellaneous Brushes -->
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="GlyphBrush" Color="#444" />

            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="LightColorBrush" Color="#DDD" />


            <Style x:Key="ButtonOlolo" TargetType="Button">
                <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true"/>
                <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
                <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource ButtonFocusVisual}"/>
                <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="23"/>
                <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="75"/>
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                            <Border 
          x:Name="Border"  
          CornerRadius="2" 
          BorderThickness="1"
          Background="{StaticResource NormalBrush}"
          BorderBrush="{StaticResource NormalBorderBrush}">
                                <ContentPresenter 
            Margin="2"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            RecognizesAccessKey="True"/>
                            </Border>
                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="true">
                                    <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource DefaultedBorderBrush}" />
                                </Trigger>
                                <Trigger Property="IsDefaulted" Value="true">
                                    <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource DefaultedBorderBrush}" />
                                </Trigger>
                                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                                    <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource DarkBrush}" />
                                </Trigger>
                                <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                                    <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource PressedBrush}" />
                                    <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource PressedBorderBrush}" />
                                </Trigger>
                                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                                    <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource DisabledBackgroundBrush}" />
                                    <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource DisabledBorderBrush}" />
                                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource DisabledForegroundBrush}"/>
                                </Trigger>
                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </ResourceDictionary>
```

And the button uses it like:

```
 <Button Style="{StaticResource ButtonOlolo}" Height="100" Width="100" Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="0"  >dddddd</Button>
```

Comment: your issue is with the button chrome. it adds allot of unexpected behaviors. 
i would completely change the control template and replace it with a border.

Comment: No, this is standart wpf button. I could do what I dlike with button chrome but it does not supports commands

Comment: i realize it's a standard wpf button. i stand by my comment before. change the button template and replace the ButtonChrome with a regular border

Comment: sorry, I dont understand how to :"and replace the ButtonChrome with a regular border" =( could you provide a sample? any way I think that will disable click animation and events

Comment: 1) do you know how  to change a controltemplate ? 
2) do you know how to see the default style + template of a button ?

Comment: 1) yes 2) https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753328(v=vs.85).aspx  - is it default template? but I have not found any default style

Comment: no, but that's the one i want you to use. place that style in your app and see your problem magically disappearing .

Comment: I have done all you said but the problem still present - could you take a look at updeted question